# Rのエラーについて：以下にエラーeval(expr, envir, enclos) : オブジェクト "cv" は存在しません

Tags: r

```
> d.svm<-svm(cv~.,data)
以下にエラーeval(expr, envir, enclos) :  オブジェクト "cv" は存在しません
```

上記のエラーはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

ご教授願います。

Comment: 念のために確認しますが、`cv`は`data`に定義された一列ですね？